# LSP software conflict with antivirus anti spyware etc programs?

Tags: c++, windows, winsock-lsp

Hello I write LSP program for reading and changing traffic. Questions is, do software like anti virus, firewall, anti spyware etc see my program as virus because LSP function?

Comment: There is more than one possible meaning of LSP here (even if I disregard candidates like Lego Space Police or Lightest Supersymmetric Particle).  Further, not all anti-virus software does the same thing, nor does it do anything like what firewalls do.

Comment: I'd say he means layered service provider as in the windows api's into add an application to the tcp/ip stack.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the firewall and antivirus program. Generally that alone would not trigger it unless you happen to match the hash signature or whatever it is using to identify viruses and spyware.